# Background Threaded TCP Server in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp, python-multithreading, tcpserver

I want to run TCP thread on the background even if I exit the main function and only stop that thread based on the received data but my code seems to close the TCP thread after it execute the SystemExit:

```
class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def setup(self):
        self._is_running = True

    def handle(self):
        while(self._is_running):
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            #some process here 
            #self._is_running is assigned based on received data 
            self.request.send(msg.encode())


    def finish(self):
        pass

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    map_server = ThreadedTCPServer(('192.168.1.101', 2002), MyTCPHandler)  
    server_thread = Thread(target=map_server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.daemon = False
    server_thread.start()
    raise SystemExit(0)
```

Comment: then what is your issue?

Comment: Thread closes the TCP thread after it execute the SystemExit, I want to run TCP thread on the background even if I exit the main function and only stop that thread based on the received data

Comment: @BrianSanchez the code in the question works for me, you would better to update code that could reproduce your issue.

Comment: Can you make the thread a process? Having a thread running after the main program exits feels wrong.